# Write an Excel macro to find and value, copy that value and paste into a Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to write an excel VBA macro to

- find a value "New Member" in a table (named "array1")
- look to and copy the cell 5 cells to the left of the found item
- paste into Cell G5
- if the value "New Member" isn't found write "not found" in cell G5

I've tried various versions of

```
        Cells.Find("New Member").Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5).Range("array1").Select
        Selection.Copy
     Range("????").Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste
        If aaa = "" Then
        MsgBox "nope"
        Else

        Range("G5").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
```

My vba excel macro skills are very new.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without all the Select/Activate stuff.

```
Dim rngFound As Range

Set rngFound = Range("Array1").Cells.Find("New Member")
  
If rngFound Is Nothing Then
    Range("G5").Value = "Not Found"
Else
    rngFound.Offset(,-5).Resize(,5).Copy Range("G5")
End If
```

Comment: Thank you this is certainly an improvement, how did you decide to copy range A5, it is likely that I'll be finding my value in column f, and on one of many rows.  It's my thought that the reference to A5 needs to be dynamic, if the value "New Member" is found on row 9, the member id will be in column a and row 9.

Comment: Thank you this is certainly an improvement. How did you decide to copy range A5 in this scenerio, it is likely that I'll be finding my value in column f, and on one of many rows?

It's my thought that the reference to A5 needs to be dynamic, if the value "New Member" is found on row 9 column G, the member id will be in column A and row 9. 

Additionally, I'm not able to find the value of "New Member" (without quotes) however, the value does exist in column G.

Comment: A5 was a typo - I changed it to G5 as that's where you said you wanted to copy to.